# Telerik window is not shown

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am using telerik window control in my popup. In some cases when the page is loaded the pop up  window skin is missing. Only the page inside window is displayed. I had searched every where for its answer but unable to find it.

Code:

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManagerUserAgreement" ShowContentDuringLoad="false"  VisibleStatusbar="false" ReloadOnShow="true" runat="server" EnableShadow="true"> 

   <Windows>  
      <telerik:RadWindow ID="UserRequestRadWindow" Title="<span style='margin- left:15px;'>Username  and Password Request</span>" runat="server" Width="400px" Height="300px" Behaviors="Close"  Skin="HCPro" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false">  
      </telerik:RadWindow> 
   </Windows>  

</telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

Comment: can you post some code...??

Comment: This post is similar to "Something has broken somewhere". If you have switching error, you should show us code where error appeared and code where error did not appear

Comment: <telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManagerUserAgreement" ShowContentDuringLoad="false"
    VisibleStatusbar="false" ReloadOnShow="true" runat="server" EnableShadow="true">
    <Windows>
        <telerik:RadWindow ID="UserRequestRadWindow" Title="<span style='margin-left:15px;'>Username and Password Request</span>"
            runat="server" Width="400px" Height="300px" Behaviors="Close" Skin="HCPro" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false">
        </telerik:RadWindow>
    </Windows>
</telerik:RadWindowManager>

Comment: Most of the times its working fine bt some time window skin is missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are under IE you may have hit the 31 stylesheets limitation this browser has. Add a **RadStyleSheetManager** to your page to combine the requests in a single file. Confirm this by testing in Firefox or Chrome as well. Also, make sure your requests are ok, your stylesheets may not be present on the page in case you are adding them dynamically and something goes wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove Skin="HCPro" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false".

HCPro is not a valid telerik skin, unless you implemented one by yourself.

Here are the valid skin names from telerik -

Black, Default, Forest, Hay, Metro, MetroTouch, Office2007,  Office2010Black, Office2010Blue, Office2010Silver, Outlook, Simple, Sitefinity, Sunset, Telerik, Transparent, Vista, Web20, WebBlue, Windows7

Comment: skin="HCPro" is implemented by me.

Comment: It becomes obvious that your custom Skin is not working properly. Where did you create your own skin? Here? http://stylebuilder.telerik.com/New.aspx